# Class function not up to date after changing instance variable

Tags: python, function, class, variables, instance

Sorry for the length of my code. This assignment deals with rectangles on a 3D plane. The class creates a box with 8 points on xyz axes from the user input centerX, centerY, centerZ, width, height, and depth. Another function in the class, setCenter, changes the centerX,centerY, and centerZ. In this example below box1.overlaps(box2) should return True.

```
>box1 = Box(10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0)
>
>box2 = Box(0, 0, 0, 3.5, 2.5, 1.0)
>
>box1.overlaps(box2)
>Out[4]: False
>
>box1.setCenter(2.75, 0.0, 0.0)
>
>box1.overlaps(box2)
>Out[6]: False
```

If I initialize the box with the center it's being changed to, it does return True

```
>box1 = Box(2.75,0,0,2,1,1)
>
>box1.overlaps(box2)
>Out[10]: True
```

How can I fix this? Is this because I'm using instance variables where I should be using class variables? If so how can I do that?

edit:updated to change points still can't get it to work as intended

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, centerX, centerY, centerZ, width, height, depth):
        self.prop = [centerX,centerY,centerZ,width,height,depth]
        self.topleft1 = [(centerX - (0.5*width)), 
            (centerY + (0.5*height)),
            (centerZ + (0.5*depth))]
        self.topright1 = [(centerX + (0.5*width)), 
            (centerY + (0.5*height)),
            (centerZ + (0.5*depth))]
        self.bottomleft1 = [(centerX - (0.5*width)), 
            (centerY - (0.5*height)),
            (centerZ + (0.5*depth))]
        self.bottomright1 = [(centerX + (0.5*width)), 
            (centerY - (0.5*height)),
            (centerZ + (0.5*depth))]
        self.topleft2 = [(centerX - (0.5*width)), 
            (centerY + (0.5*height)),
            (centerZ - (0.5*depth))]
        self.topright2 = [(centerX + (0.5*width)),
            (centerY + (0.5*height)),
            (centerZ - (0.5*depth))]
        self.bottomleft2 = [(centerX - (0.5*width)), 
        (centerY - (0.5*height)),
        (centerZ - (0.5*depth))]
        self.bottomright2 = [(centerX + (0.5*width)), 
                (centerY - (0.5*height)),
                (centerZ - (0.5*depth))]
        self.coord = [self.topleft1,self.topright1,self.bottomleft1,self.bottomright1,self.topleft2,
                  self.topright2,self.bottomleft2,self.bottomright2]
    def setCenter(self, x1, y1, z1):
        self.prop[0] = x1
        self.prop[1] = y1
        self.prop[2] = z1
        self.topleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
    def setWidth(self, width):
        self.prop[3] = width
        self.topleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
    def setHeight(self, height):
        self.prop[4] = height
        self.topleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
    def setDepth(self, depth):
        self.prop[5] = depth
        self.topleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft1 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright1 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] + (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.topright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] + (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomleft2 = [(self.prop[0] - (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
        self.bottomright2 = [(self.prop[0] + (0.5*self.prop[3])), 
        (self.prop[1] - (0.5*self.prop[4])),
        (self.prop[2] - (0.5*self.prop[5]))]
    def volume(self):
        return (self.prop[3]*self.prop[4]*self.prop[5])
    def surfaceArea(self):
        return (self.prop[3]*self.prop[4])*2+(self.prop[3]*self.prop[5])*2+(self.prop[4]*self.prop[5])*2
    def insideOf(self, point):
        if all([point[0]>=self.topleft1[0],point[0]<=self.topright1[0],point[1]>=self.bottomleft1[1],point[1]<=self.topleft1[1],point[2]>=self.topleft2[2],point[2]<=self.topleft1[2]]):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def overlaps(self, otherBox):
        result = False
        for i in otherBox.coord:
            if self.insideOf(i) == True:
                result = True
        for i in self.coord:
            if otherBox.insideOf(i) == True:
                result = True
        return result
    def contains(self, otherBox):
        if self.insideOf(otherBox.topleft1) and self.insideOf(otherBox.bottomright1) and self.insideOf(otherBox.topleft2) and self.insideOf(otherBox.bottomright2) == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.prop[3] == int(self.prop[3]):
            self.x = int(self.prop[3])
        else:
            self.x = self.prop[3]
        if self.prop[4] == int(self.prop[4]):
            self.y = int(self.prop[4])
        else:
            self.y = self.prop[4]
        if self.prop[5] == int(self.prop[5]):
            self.z = int(self.prop[5])
        else:
            self.z = self.prop[5]
        self.dimensions = str(self.x)+'-by-'+str(self.y)+'-by-'+str(self.z)
        if self.prop[5] == 0:
            self.D = ' 2D'
        else:
            self.D = ' 3D'
            self.center = '('+str(self.prop[0])+','+str(self.prop[1])+','+str(self.prop[2])+')'

        return '< '+self.dimensions+self.D+' box with center at '+self.center+' >'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your setCenter() method. In it, you are updating the centers of the box, but you're not updating topleft1, topright1, bottomleft1, etc.

Change your setCenter() method to also update these properties, and it should work. (You'll also have to add this change to your other setX methods. You should abstract these computations into their own private method, and call it at the end of each setX method.).

Comment: I'm still having trouble :/

Comment: Ah, you also have to update self.coord as you do in the constructor, since that's what you're using in the overlap method.
But again, all that copy-pasting is really not good. I'd put it in a method called updateCorners(self)